# Vertical menu always open in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, frontend

I have a website where I want the vertical menu to open always, I am looking for a property to do that. I am new to front end development, so i dont have any code to show.

But this is what i want. I want the vertical menu to be always visible irrespective of mouse hover.

This is the default view when the page loads
[image: This is the view when the page loads]

This is the view when i hover the mouse on "All departments"
[image: This is the view when i hover the mouse here]

Comment: insert code pls

Comment: Yes we will need to see the code or at the very least, a public url where we can inspect your current HTML and CSS

Comment: If it helps, this is from the demo page. https://demo2.wpopal.com/ekommart/ekommart-home-5/#

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be self contained, so please edit your question to include the relevant code that you are using in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). External links are ok, but only when the relevant code is *also* included as links can change or break over time and make the question invalid.

Comment: As i mentioned, i am not a front end developer and i was hoping to get some lead if not exact answer. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is what displays the menu:

```
.vertical-navigation:hover .vertical-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

.vertical-menu is visible when .vertical-navigation is hovered.

If you remove the hover property it will always display, you can do this by overriding and adding this css:

```
.vertical-navigation .vertical-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```